# how to align this page contnet without horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I am creating simple website using CSS flexbox, but from some reasons my layout in `About.vue` stretch out with this horizontal bar only this component is in `mainLayout.vue`, and I can't figure out what is wrong making this problem. Did someone know how to fix it?

[image: img]

MainLayout.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper--main">
    <Navbar />
    <Hero />
    <main>
      <slot />
    </main>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Hero from "../components/Hero.vue";
import Footer from "../components/Footer.vue";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.vue";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  components: { Navbar, Footer, Hero },
});
</script>
<style lang="sass">
@import "../styles/mainLayout.sass"
@import "../styles/variables.sass"
@import "../styles/utilitys.sass"
</style>
```

MainLayout.sass

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap')
*,
*::before,
*::after
    box-sizing: border-box
    margin: 0px
    padding: 0px

img,
picture,
svg
    max-width: 100%
    display: block
    object-fit: cover

img
    object-fit: cover
@media (min-width: 768px)
    html
        font-size: 130%

body
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif
    font-weight: 400
    line-height: 1.65
    max-width: 2000px
    background-color: hsl(var(--white))
    color: hsl(var(--text))

.wrapper--main
    display: grid
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto
    min-height: 100vh

main
    display: grid
    gap: var(--size-fluid-6)
    margin-bottom: var(--size-fluid-5)
    margin-top: var(--size-fluid-5)
```

Index.vue

```
<template>
  <MainLayout><About /> </MainLayout>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import MainLayout from "../layouts/MainLayout.vue";
import About from "../components/About.vue";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  components: { MainLayout, About },
});
</script>
<style lang="sass">
</style>
```

About.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="about-container">
    <div class="wrapper gap">
      <div class="title-container--about gap--sm">
        <div class="title-wrapper">
          <h2 class="h2">lorem ipsum</h2>
          <p class="title-container--sm">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolor
            iusto impedit molestiae quo, labore perspiciatis quia, deserunt quis
            nobis asperiores, delectus ut! Quaerat ut molestiae sunt ex
            molestias fuga quis. orem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
            adipisicing elit. Dolor iusto impedit molestiae quo, labore
            perspiciatis quia, deserunt quis nobis asperiores, delectus ut!
            Quaerat ut molestiae sunt ex molestias fuga quis.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow--map">
          <img class="icon--lg" src="../icons/arrow-map.svg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-about-btn-map">
          <img class="icon--lg about-map" src="../icons/map.svg" alt="" />
          <button class="btn btn--primary about-btn">lorem ipsum</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img class="img-about only-desktop" src="../img/about.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang='ts'>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({});
</script>
<style lang="sass">
.title-container--sm
  width: var(--size-fluid-10)
  flex-grow: 0
.about-map
  margin-right: auto
.about-btn
  margin-right: auto
.container-about--btn-map
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: center
  width: 200px
.gap--sm
  gap: var(--size-fluid-4)
.title-container--about
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
.arrow--map
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
.gap
  gap: var(--size-fluid-8)
.about-container
  margin-left: var(--size-fluid-7)
  margin-right: var(--size-fluid-7)
@media (max-width: 1440px)
  .only-desktop
    display: none
</style>
```

Comment: There are several ways to hide a scrollbar, the best way is always to find where the extra space is coming from and solve the problem at its root. So my general advice is to use the developer tools, click the arrow icon and see what's causing the extra space. Eventually start eliminating elements until it disappears, you'll find the culprit :)

Comment: I know this, I rebuild this layout seven times, but even after it, I can't find out where are these extra spaces coming from, parent container `wrapper--main` have correct width but his child `main` tag have these extra spaces, seriously i tried already a lot of things to fix this. But I see that I need to ask people more experience them me :(

Comment: you don't need to rebuild the layout, you just can just right click the element in the "elements" tab of developer tools, then select "delete element". If you find the culprit, you'll notice that hovering it with the "arrow" tool you'll see the empty space will take a color, according to the color you can understand if it's a problem with width, margin or padding. You can also edit the css and check the solution without rebuilding

Comment: The fact is that it's really hard to reproduce the problem in our systems, since you only have the built page. So I gave you some hint, I'm sure you'll find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
html, body
    ...
    max-width: 2000px
    width: 100vw
    overflow-x: hidden
```

Although the `overflow-x` should be a last-resort if the method above fails.

**An explanation of why it works**

Well, the `max-width` property you put for the body element only says that the width of the body should not exceed a certain value. Your html element also has a width of its own, and by default thats the viewport (screen) width.
So if your body content stretches out in the y axis, your body element will expand to a maximum of the value you set inorder to accomodate that content, which means it will overflow the width of your html element.

Specifying `width: 100vw` means that the body will be of the same width as the html element and should not exceed that.

The `max-width` property only comes into play when the screen size is really large — e.g. on desktops — and you want to limit the width of the page content. That's not something that's typically done, because **all** the page content will be stuck to one side of the screen. I'm sure this is not your desired effect beacause this also means full-width elements like your navbar will not stretch across the entire screen.

Comment: This works for me thx :) can you explain how this works ?